# Encryption in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I have stumbled across the below snippet, which encrypts a user's password.  This is what i want to do because I don't want to store the user's password in the database without any encryption.

This is working fine for what I want to achieve, but my question is this:  how can I un-encrypt it to make sure the value they have entered in the password box matches?

```
// Hash the password details of the user!
private static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)
{
  string saltAndPwd = string.Concat(pwd, salt);
  string hashedPwd = 
    FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltAndPwd, "SHA1");
  hashedPwd = string.Concat(hashedPwd, salt);
  return hashedPwd;
}
```

I call the above like this

```
string password = CreatePasswordHash(TxtPassword.Text, "1579");
```

The password then becomes something like this: `566DAB495AD0747B49865F9177E430DFAD63CA281579`

So how do I un-encrypt that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't un-encrypt. You hash the password the user entered, with the same salt, and check if the hash is the identical to what you stored in the db.

Comment: You cannot (and don't need to) do that. The reason people use hashes is because it is not possible to reverse them

Comment: Use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` for password hashing, and not `HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile`

Comment: @CodeInChaos iv just replace haspasswordforstoringinconfigfile with what you have said but it gives me this error system.web.security.formsauthentication does not contain a definition for Rfc2898DeriveBytes  ???

Comment: [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) is a class.

Comment: Don't try to create an authentication system yourself.  Use [asp.net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 8):

First off, **do not attempt to write your own password storage system**. You will get it wrong and build an insecure system. Hire an expert who specializes in this sort of thing, have them write the system, and train you in its correct usage and maintenance.

Second, the whole *point* of that code is that it is impossible for you to find out the user's password. **Their password is none of your business.** The point of the salted hash is *to build a verification system whereby you do not have to store their password in the first place* but you can still verify that *they* know their password.

To understand how that works, read my four-part series of articles on that subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/salt/

But again **do not attempt to do this yourself**. Hire an expert with decades of experience in this space if you need to do security work.

Comment: "Hire an expert" --- haha, if only every asker on SO hired a professional instead of doing it themselves - then no one would post questions here

Comment: @zerkms: There are plenty of situations in which "learning as you go" is appropriate. Particularly if the cost of making a mistake is relatively small. Building security systems is not one of them.

Comment: @zerkms: Use the ASP.NET Membership system and you have hired a whole team of experts. For free. And there is plenty left to ask about how to use it.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: a) I'm not OP, so I don't need that b) ASP.NET Membership has nothing magic and doesn't automatically protect from anything to call it silver bullet

Answer (score 5):

The point of a hash is that **no-one** can decrypt it!

When a user attempts a login, you hash the entered password, and then compare the hash with what's in the database. If the hash matches, then the password was correct.

Comment: everybody can decrypt it. The problem is the enormous cost of decryption.

Comment: @lukas: bruteforce is not a decryption. Decryption always leads to a known result in a known time.